# How to know if function was called by an element with addEventListener?

Tags: javascript

I made a localization script so I can have my project in multiple languages, and now I'm not sure how to do something.

First of all, I have the script to get the client's browser language (in my case, mine is Spanisn -es-),
and then gets all the strings of the page and places them in their position basically like this:

```
let texts = {
    "en": {
        "divId1": "Message 1",
        "divId2": "Message 2",
    },
    "es" : {
        "divId1": "Mensaje 1",
        "divId2": "Mensaje 2",
    }
}
```

So that when the select box that contains the available languages and has an addEventListener with "change" event, triggers the "change" event, all the text in the page changes to the respective language.

Now, everything works flawlessly, as expected, but I have a div that will act as an alert when the user writes the username or password incorrectly, and both errors with a different message, but the way I have the script, the only way to change this text dinamically is checking if the language change was done because the "change" event was triggered instead of the first page load.

So, my problem here is: How do I know when the function that display the text was called by the "change" trigger instead of the initial page load call?

Here is a GIF of how it works and the code at the end if you need it, hope I explained myself correctly.

[image: a]

LOCALIZATION SCRIPT:

```
import { texts } from './lang.js';

// Gets the current client's browser language.
let clientLanguage = window.navigator.language;

// Defines currently available system languages.
let languages = {
    "en": "English",
    "es": "Español", 
};

// Default system language
let systemLanguage = "en";

// Adds available system languages to the currentLanguage selector (right corner of the navbar).
for ( let i = 0; i < Object.keys( languages ).length; i++ ) {
    document.getElementById("selectLanguage").innerHTML += "<option id=" + Object.keys( languages )[i] + ">" + Object.values( languages )[i] + "</option>";
}

// Checks if user's client language is available in system.
// If it available, system will be in this language by default. If it isn't, system will be in the language chosen by default.
Object.keys( texts ).forEach( ( currentLoopLang ) => {
    if ( currentLoopLang == clientLanguage ) {
        systemLanguage = clientLanguage;
    }
});
document.getElementById( systemLanguage ).selected = true;

// Adds the function that allow to change the language of the system when the language selected in the language selector changes.
document.getElementById("selectLanguage").addEventListener( "change", ( option ) => {
    changeSystemLanguage( option.target.options[option.target.selectedIndex].id );
});

// Calls the translation system everytime the page loads.
changeSystemLanguage( systemLanguage );

// Function that performs the translation of the system language (basically, it adds the text to the elements in the clients lang).
function changeSystemLanguage( lang ) {
    for ( let i = 0; i < Object.keys( texts[lang] ).length; i++ ) {
        let currentTextKey = Object.keys(texts[lang])[i];
        let currentTextValue= Object.values(texts[lang])[i];
        let currentTextCheck = document.getElementById( currentTextKey );
        if ( document.contains( currentTextCheck ) ) {
            switch ( currentTextCheck.tagName ) {
                case ("INPUT"):
                    if ( currentTextCheck.type === "text" || currentTextCheck.type === "password" || currentTextCheck.type === "email" ) {
                        currentTextCheck.placeholder = currentTextValue;
                    } else if ( currentTextCheck.type === "button" ) {
                        document.getElementById( currentTextKey ).value = currentTextValue;
                    }
                    break;
                /* 
                case ("DIV"):
                    HERE IS MY PROBLEM. I NEED TO MAKE AN IF STATEMENT THAT CHECKS IF THIS FUNCTION WAS CALLED BY
                    "CHANGE" EVENT OF THE selectLanguage (SELECT ELEMENT ID) INSTEAD OF THE INICIAL CALL THAT WORKS AS
                    THE FIRST PAGE LOAD AS YOU CAN SEE ABOVE THIS FUNCTION.
                    break;
                */
                default:
                    console.log( currentTextKey );
                    document.getElementById( currentTextKey ).innerHTML = currentTextValue;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AND THE LANGS SCRIPT:

```
// List of full system texts
export let texts = {
    "en": {
        "txtSysTitle":                  "TASKMANAGER",
        "txtSysLoginWelcomeBack":       "Welcome back!",
        "txtSysLoginSubWelcomeBack":    "Please, sign in with your username and password to proceed.",
        "sysLoginUsername":             "Username",
        "sysLoginPassword":             "Password",
        "sysLoginLogin":                "Login",
        "sysLoginRecovery":             "Forgot your details?",
        "txtSysRecoveryHeader":         "Recover your details",
        "txtSysRecoverySubHeader":      "To recover your details (both username and password), just write in the form below the email address associated with that account, then press the button to proceed.",
        "sysRecoveryEmail":             "Email address (example@gmail.com)",
        "sysRecoverySubmit":            "Proceed to recover my details",
        "sysRecoveryLogin":             "I want to return to the login",
        "txtLoginUsernameError":        "The introduced username is not correct.",
        "txtLoginPasswordError":        "The introduced password is not correct.",
    },
    "es": {
        "txtSysTitle":                  "TASKMANAGER",
        "txtSysLoginWelcomeBack":       "¡Bienvenido de nuevo!",
        "txtSysLoginSubWelcomeBack":    "Por favor, inicia sesión con tu usuario y contraseña para continuar.",
        "sysLoginUsername":             "Nombre de usuario",
        "sysLoginPassword":             "Contraseña",
        "sysLoginLogin":                "Iniciar sesión",
        "sysLoginRecovery":             "¿Has olvidado tus datos?",
        "txtSysRecoveryHeader":         "Recupere sus datos",
        "txtSysRecoverySubHeader":      "Para recuperar sus datos (nombre de usuario y contraseña), sólo escriba en el formulario a continuación la dirección de correo electrónico asociada con esa cuenta y después pulse el botón para continuar.",
        "sysRecoveryEmail":             "Correo electrónico (ejemplo@gmail.com)",
        "sysRecoverySubmit":            "Continuar para recuperar mis datos",
        "sysRecoveryLogin":             "Deseo volver al inicio de sesión",
        "txtLoginUsernameError":        "El nombre de usuario introducido no es correcto.",
        "txtLoginPasswordError":        "La contraseña introducida no es correcta.",
    },
};
```

Comment: Pass an extra parameter from the event handler function ..?

Comment: You can use [Event.isTrusted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted) read-only property.